# Make Mathematica aware of private root certificate authority

Tags: web-access

I have a private root certificate authority and when I use functions like `URLRead[]` to connect to a local HTTPS endpoint, I have to add `VerifySecurityCertificates -> False`.

How do I make Mathematica aware of, and accept this private root CA?

**Edit:**

This seems easily solvable by understanding where Mathematica looks to verify a certificate. Presumably, it would either keep it's own directory of globally trusted certificates, or use the OS's.

Does it keep it's own? If so, where are they located?

Comment: This is just a guess, but I think Mathematica most probably uses java for this in the background, so it would be worth a try to look into the java RE that comes with it: `FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", 
  "Java", $SystemID}]`. There is the standard `keytool` executable in the `bin` subdir and a `cacerts` keystore-file in the `lib/security` subdirectory. I would try `bin/keytool` to add the desired certificate to `lib/security/cacerts` and see if that works...

Comment: @AlbertRetey When I saw your suggestion I was sure this would work. But I tried it and unfortunately (and surprisingly) it doesn't.

Comment: ok, sorry for your efforts, good to know anyway...

Comment: The answer might change a little bit depending on version and platform, but in general recent versions use the native SSL backend (Schannel on Windows and Secure Transport on macOS) as well as NSS on Linux, so the certificates can be managed using the appropriate OS tools on each platform.

Comment: @ilian: thanks for that information, I think that would be worth an answer, wouldn't it?